# Managing subviews from superview?

Tags: cocoa

I have a window with a content view. I load a subview on to it from a different nib file programmatically. is there any way that a change on the subview can be captured by the controls on the window's content view?

For instance, I have a tableview on the subview. If the selection of this tableView changes, i want to enable a button on the windows's content view.
Is it possible? If yes, please guide..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are few ways

You can set the object that creates the subview as a delegate for the tableview and implement `tableViewSelectionDidChange`in that object.

Or you can subscribe to `NSTableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification` notification, passing your tableView:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tableViewSelectionDidChange:) name:NSTableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification object:tableView];
```

and handle it in :

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSTableView *tableView = (NSTableView *)aNotification.object;
    NSLog(@"selection changed: %i", [tableView selectedRow]);
}
```

Comment: Sounds logical to me...Thanks so much! I will try this...If i come across any issues, i'll post :)